# Was the following moderator review action fair?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, moderators

I voted to Reopen the following post [Resizing attribute table on QGIS print layout](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401464/resizing-attribute-table-on-qgis-print-layout), and I left a [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401464/resizing-attribute-table-on-qgis-print-layout#comment707769_401464) (the only comment there so far) justifying why I thought it should have been reopen:

> Voting to reopen as the question is perfectly fine. Asking it to be more focused is non-sense because aligning text within a table and resizing columns to fit such aligned text are almost tasks one does altogether. Such that is, answers show it is the same approach/logic which addresses both topics. We should not take a number/bullet formatting literally

@PolyGeo was the one who closed it in the first place with a single moderator binding vote. So far, so good.

[image]

After I voted to reopen, it had collected two more reopen votes and was probably in the way of being reopened. But PolyGeo came in again and cast another moderator closing (leave closed) binding vote ([link to review](https://gis.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/231654)).

[image]

Is this fair? At minimum odd? It seems like abusing the binding vote privilege; i.e., cast it once, and then, unilaterally overrule another 3 contrary votes to keep own's previous decision? What?

Comment: The post is now open again, do you know what happened with it since you posed this question?